# Solution of convection dominated PDE with conditions only on the interior of the domain

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method

I'm Trying to solve the following PDE:

$$ \frac{1}{20}\left(2 x_1^2+x_2^2\right) -25\left( \begin{bmatrix} 0\\ \frac{6 \cos(x_1)}{-37 + 3 \cos(2 x_1)} \end{bmatrix}^\intercal \nabla_{x_1,x_2}V(x_1,x_2) \right)^2 + \begin{bmatrix} x_2\\ \frac{6 (-98 + x_2^2 \cos(x_1)) \sin(x_1)}{-37 + 3 \cos(2 x_1)} \end{bmatrix}^\intercal \nabla_{x_1,x_2}V(x_1,x_2) = 0  $$

The only condition I have is $V(0,0)=0$ and I am looking for a positive 
definite solution. To give some context, this comes from a Hamilton-Jacobi-Bellman PDE.

```
ClearAll[RHS]
RHS = 1/20 (2 x1^2 + x2^2) - 25({0, (6 Cos[x1])/(-37 + 3 Cos[2 x1])}.Inactive[Grad][V[x1, x2], {x1, x2}])^2 + {x2,( 6 (-98 + x2^2 Cos[x1]) Sin[x1])/(-37 + 3 Cos[2 x1])}.Inactive[Grad][V[x1, x2], {x1, x2}]

ClearAll[ufun, mesh]
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
mesh = ToElementMesh[Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}], "MaxBoundaryCellMeasure" -> 0.005, "MeshElementType" -> TriangleElement];

ufun = NDSolveValue[{RHS == 0, DirichletCondition[V[x1, x2] == 0, x1 == 0 && x2 == 0]}, V, {x1, x2} \[Element] mesh]

Plot3D[ufun[x1, x2], {x1, 0, 1}, {x2, 0, 1}, ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", AxesLabel -> Automatic]
```

Which gives some interpolating function with the warning: The PDE is convection dominated and the result may not be stable. Adding artificial diffusion may help. I am looking for a solution on a rather larger domain (e.g. 
Rectangle[{-10, -10}, {10, 10}), but I am finding several problems. First, I am not sure on how to enforce the condition $V(0,0)=0$ if (0,0) is not in the boundary of the region. Second, I am not sure on how to enforce the fact that V should be positive on the region and finally, I am not sure how to get rid of that warning about the PDE being convection dominated.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is it possible to rearrange the problem in the form of the objective functional and the transition function(or variational form)? it's much easier to understand the problem.

Comment: Sure, it is an inverted pendulum on a cart with objective: 1/10 x1^2 + 1/20 x2^2 + 1/100 u^2. The dynamics of the pendulum are standard, (two states, angles measured from the vertical, length 1/2, mass of the pendulum 2 and mass of the cart 8. The cart dynamics are neglected and the cart acceleration taken as the control. The right-hand side of the ODE can be reconstructed as $\dot x = f(x(t)) + g(x(t)) u(t)$ with $f(x) = {x_2,( 6 (-98 + x_2^2 \cos(x_2)) \sin(x_1))/(-37 + 3 \cos(2 x_1))}$ (the vectorfield multiplying the second gradient) and $g(x)={0, (6 \cos(x_1))/(-37 + 3 \cos(2 x_1))}$

Comment: Was that what you meant?

Comment: yes, that forms make it easier to understand the problem :)

Answer (score 2):

This is a nonlinear equation. To be able to use FEM you have to get the equation into the coefficient form:

[image]

Since the form you present is not in this coefficient form strange things happen. The easiest way around this is probably to use `Activate` and have the FEM solver figure it out - which seems to work in this case but is not a general cure.

```
ClearAll[ufun, mesh]
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
mesh = ToElementMesh[Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}], 
   "MaxBoundaryCellMeasure" -> 0.005, 
   "MeshElementType" -> TriangleElement];
Block[{e = 1, s = 1, j = 1}, 
 ufun = NDSolveValue[{Activate[RHS] == 0, 
    DirichletCondition[V[x1, x2] == 0, x1 == 0 && x2 == 0]}, 
   V, {x1, x2} \[Element] mesh, 
   Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", 
       "PDESolveOptions" -> {"FindRootOptions" -> {EvaluationMonitor \
:> e++, StepMonitor :> s++, 
           Jacobian -> {Automatic, EvaluationMonitor :> j++}}}}}];
 {"Steps" -> s, "Function Evaluations" -> e, 
  "Jacobian Evaluations" -> j}]
```

This gives messages

```
InitializePDECoefficients::femcscd: The PDE is convection dominated and the result may not be stable. Adding artificial diffusion may help.

InitializePDECoefficients::femcscd: The PDE is convection dominated and the result may not be stable. Adding artificial diffusion may help.

FindRoot::dfmin: The minimal damping factor of 1/10000 has been reached.

{"Steps" -> 6, "Function Evaluations" -> 9, 
 "Jacobian Evaluations" -> 5}
```

Yes, the PDE is convection dominated. This is a warning. Not all convection dominated PDEs are unstable. But the bigger problem is that the nonlinear solver can not find a solution. You could try to help it with specifying an `InitialSeeding`. The ones I tried did not work, but you may know more about the problem.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this. I was wondering tho if this would help with the fact that I need a solution on Rectangle[{a,b},{c,d}] with zero in the interior of the domain. I don't have my mathematica at hand, but I remember that the solver was complaining that V[0,0]=0 needed to be specified on the boundary. Also, If you could quickly comment on what sort of Initial seeding is needed. Thanks!.

Comment: Do you impose zero with a DirichletConditon? Make sure the ElementMesh has a node there by using the "IncludePoints" option to ToElementMesh. To see how `InitialsSeeding` is to be used have a look at the ref page.